# Matching names in excel with middle names and extra space

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search through a list of names to find people within other segments of data. If we have them I have an 'IF'statement that returns 'Match' and 'FALSE' if not. The issue I'm running into is that some of the names pulled from the other databases have odd spaces after the first initial and middle initials that aren't in the first issuance of the name. Is there a way for me to match these names regardless?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkNmv.png)

So what I would be doing is comparing the 1st name between the other 2 provided names.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the TRIM function?
And you can create few other columns that will contain the possible combinations of the Name and then try applying the conditions.

Comment: Microsoft has an add-in called fuzzy matching that serves my purposes. Thanks though!